# java atomics operations

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

Is correct to divide the following statements:

```
int v = ++j;
```

as:

1. read j value (atomic);
2. increment by 1 the value read (NON
   atomic possibly interference by
   other thread);
3. write the adding result to i
   (atomic);
4. write i into v (atomic)

Comment: What is the goal of this question?  To understand what bytecode is generated by the compiler?  To understand how to make this threadsafe?

Comment: Simply to know if operations that are not read/write are atomic or not.

Comment: Look at list of actions: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.2 ; for the purpose of the memory model, it's irrelevant whether adding numbers is atomic or not. It's the read/write that matters. Java language does not have a read-modify-write as one atomic action.

Comment: Also note that `v` is not volatile, so there is no guarantee writes to it are ever seen by other reading threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `int` (or smaller datatypes) read/write/arithmetic operations are atomic. References (read/write) are also atomic, regardless of whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit.

However, operations on 64-bit `long` and `double` may not be atomic.

#### [JLS 17.7 Non-atomic Treatment of `double` and `long`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.7)

> Some implementations may find it convenient to divide a single write action on a 64-bit `long` or `double` value into two write actions on adjacent 32 bit values. For efficiency's sake, this behavior is implementation specific; Java virtual machines are free to perform writes to `long` and `double` values atomically or in two parts.
>
> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-`volatile` `long` or `double` value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64 bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write. Writes and reads of `volatile long` and `double` values are always atomic. Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32 or 64 bit values.
>
> VM implementors are encouraged to avoid splitting their 64-bit values where possible. Programmers are encouraged to declare shared 64-bit values as `volatile` or synchronize their programs correctly to avoid possible complications.

Note that neither pre- nor post- increment/decrement operators themselves are atomic, not even on `int` or `byte`: the read/write/arithmetic operations happens in distinctly separate steps.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Essentials/Concurrency/Atomic Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)

Comment: See also JLS guarantee against Word Tearing http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.6

Comment: Thanks, but again really I don't understand if step 2 is atomic or not. You and others, it seems, say not while Stephen say yes. I'm confused. My be i++ as whole is considered not atomic while all the divided sub-operations are atomic (including increment)????

Comment: @xdevel2000: what really matters is the atomicity of the reads and writes. `i++` may consist of an atomic read, followed by an atomic write, but as a whole is not one atomic "read-add-write" operation.

Answer (score 1):

Close.  Step 2 is atomic.  In this case `j` must be one of `byte`, `char`, `short` or `int`, and each of these can be loaded and stored atomically.

Once a value has been loaded into a hardware register, there should be no possibility that another thread can interfere with it.  There's probably something in the JLS about the atomicity of primitive operations ... but I cannot spot it.

Comment: Or `double`. (And not `volatile`.) In the example code it can't be `long` or `double`.

Comment: Step 2 is atomic? Why? In many books I read that only read/write operations are atomic!

Comment: @xdevel2000 Looking back at the (current) question steps 1 and 3 could sheer with different datatypes.

Comment: @xdevel2000: In step 2 the loaded value is incremented. It's atomic (or maybe the term atomic just doesn't apply here) because the loaded value is local to the thread, so no other can modify it. (but another thread may do the read before the first thread does the write, so an increment may still be skipped)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Incrementing an int results in three steps (thus it is not atomic), assigning it is another step. Here is the resulting bytecode:

```
..
istore_1
iinc    1, 1
iload_1
istore_2
..
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement%28%29)

```
AtomicInteger j; // do init

int v = j.incrementAndGet();
```

A quick view with [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) shows the following byte code for the instructions:

```
    int j = 0;
//    0    0:iconst_0
//    1    1:istore_1
    int v = ++j;
//    2    2:iinc            1  1
//    3    5:iload_1
//    4    6:istore_2
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I wish to know only if the JVM divides the above operations as I wrote.